# Abrir programa externo via mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em fazer uma operação. Tenho uma aplicação console que abre um PDF. Esse console leva o nome de Servico.exe, apesar de ter o nome de servico, ele é um exe e não um serviço. Esse abrir o PDF está ok. Criei um projeto MVC5. Usei o `ADO .Net Entity Framework` o que levou o colega Morrison afirmar que essa era uma péssima abordagem, mas como é apenas uma POC fui em frente e depois vejo outra abordagem. A minha dificuldade está em abrir o programa que chama o relatório via de dentro da controller ou view. Abaixo a controller que deverá fazer isso. Essa controller foi gerada pelo wizard do VS2013. Não consigo montar uma action ou um método que faça isso.

```
public class AppealReportController : Controller
    {
        private ReportDBContext db = new ReportDBContext();

        // GET: AppealReport
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO = db.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.Include(p => p.POC_RELATORIO);
            return View(await pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: AppealReport/Details/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO = await db.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.FindAsync(id);
            if (pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
        }

        // GET: AppealReport/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ID_RELATORIO = new SelectList(db.POC_RELATORIO, "ID_RELATORIO", "NM_RELATORIO");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: AppealReport/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO,ID_RELATORIO,ID_USUARIO,DT_SOLICITACAO,DT_AGENDAMENTO,DT_GERACAO,BL_RELATORIO")] POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.Add(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ID_RELATORIO = new SelectList(db.POC_RELATORIO, "ID_RELATORIO", "NM_RELATORIO", pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.ID_RELATORIO);
            return View(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
        }

        // GET: AppealReport/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO = await db.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.FindAsync(id);
            if (pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.ID_RELATORIO = new SelectList(db.POC_RELATORIO, "ID_RELATORIO", "NM_RELATORIO", pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.ID_RELATORIO);
            return View(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
        }

        // POST: AppealReport/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO,ID_RELATORIO,ID_USUARIO,DT_SOLICITACAO,DT_AGENDAMENTO,DT_GERACAO,BL_RELATORIO")] POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.ID_RELATORIO = new SelectList(db.POC_RELATORIO, "ID_RELATORIO", "NM_RELATORIO", pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.ID_RELATORIO);
            return View(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
        }

        // GET: AppealReport/Delete/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO = await db.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.FindAsync(id);
            if (pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
        }

        // POST: AppealReport/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO = await db.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.FindAsync(id);
            db.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.Remove(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Tentei isso e não deu certo:

```
public void openApplication()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Projetos\\Servicos\\bin\\Servicos.exe");
        }
```

E fiz essa chamada:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO,ID_RELATORIO,ID_USUARIO,DT_SOLICITACAO,DT_AGENDAMENTO,DT_GERACAO,BL_RELATORIO")] POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.Add(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
                openApplication();//Aqui não funfa
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ID_RELATORIO = new SelectList(db.POC_RELATORIO, "ID_RELATORIO", "NM_RELATORIO", pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.ID_RELATORIO);
            return View(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
        }
```

Comment: Como a pergunta ficou ampla, fiz uma edição e alterei o título e o conteúdo apenas para a abertura de um programa executável externo no mvc.

Comment: Tem um problema grande de abordagem aí. Uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC é uma aplicação Web, portanto não é feita para abrir executáveis, mesmo que locais. Um clássico disso é o pacote [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa), que gera um PDF chamando um executável e não funciona em instâncias Web do Windows Azure, por exemplo. De qualquer forma, eu vou responder sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, o que você faz é o mesmo que o [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa) faz, então vou reproduzir [o método que invoca o serviço](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/blob/master/Rotativa/WkhtmlDriver.cs) com algumas alterações para o seu caso, lê a saída dele e converte num array de bytes, que é o conteúdo do PDF:

```
    protected static byte[] AbrirExecutavelExtrairPdf()
    {
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Projetos\Servicos\bin\Servicos.exe",
                Arguments = "",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Projetos\Servicos\bin",
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var sOut = proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read;

                while ((read = sOut.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }

            string error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            if (ms.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(error);
            }

            proc.WaitForExit();

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Só não entendi os parâmetros no método AbrirExecutavelExtrairPdf. Eles não são usados em lugar algum.

Comment: Na verdade eles não precisam. Usei o método que apontei pra fazer um mais simples pra você e esqueci de retirar os parâmetros. Agora está ok.

Comment: Deu certo abrir o exe, valeu. Vou marcar sua resposta.

Comment: Cigano, como eu abro esse arquivo gerado? No banco ficou um número e não sei como abrir para ver se é o relatório ou se deu erro.

Comment: Convertendo o array de bytes em arquivo. Pode ser o caso de ter que fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: Ok, vou queimar uns neurônios e se não conseguir nada, abro outro post.